# Python - Find and destroy duplicate items in a list

Tags: python, list

In Python, is there a way to check for duplicate items in a list, and if there is, then remove them? I'm looking for something like this:

```
>>> def check():
>>>    # put code here
>>> list = ["foo", "foo", "bar"]
>>> check(list)
>>> list
["foo", "bar"]
>>> list2 = ["foo", "bar", "example"]
>>> check(list2)
>>> list2
["foo", "bar", "example"]
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

Guys, I'm really new at programming, and the order doesn't really matter. So a `for` loop should be fine. But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `set` might be a better data structure here, as it can't have duplicates in the first place. You can also use it as a tool to uniquify your list:

```
>>> lst = ["bar", "foo", "foo"]
>>> set(lst)
set(['foo', 'bar'])
>>> list(set(lst))
['foo', 'bar']
```

Or if you need to preserve the order, you can keep your data in an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict.fromkeys(lst)
>>> d
OrderedDict([('bar', None), ('foo', None)])
>>> list(d)
['bar', 'foo']
```

Note that for performance reasons it would be more ideal to use the right data structure in the first place, rather than using a raw list and removing duplicates from it after every operation using one of these transformations.

Comment: Much better. On Python 2 it's just `d.keys()` and if a `dictview` works (which it usually will where a `tuple` would) you can use the same on Python 3.

Comment: @agf: I don't see what you mean by "usually will where a tuple would". `KeysView` doesn't even support indexing.

Comment: I was trying to imply you can't mutate it yourself, but you can iterate over it, and it has a `len` -- that it's an immutable sized iterable container. A tuple wasn't a good example :)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>>lis = ["foo", "foo", "bar"]
>>>lis=list(set(lis))
>>>print(lis)
['foo','bar']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to retain the order in the list:

```
s = set()
new_list = [v for v in old_list if not (v in s or s.add(v))]
```

If `v` is not yet in `s`, then `s.add(v)` is evaluated and returns None, so the value is taken. Otherwise, `v in s` is True, and the value is skipped.

If you don't care of the order, just use `set()` as already recommended.

Answer (score 0):

This IDLE session will show a convenient Python way to remove duplicate items by converting to a set, where duplicates are removed by converting.

```
>>>lis = ["foo", "foo", "bar"]
>>>list(set(lis))
```

Answer (score 0):

If using python > 2.4

`mylist = ["foo", "foo", "bar"]`

`myList = sorted(set(myList))`

Output

`['bar', 'foo']`